# Calculate N-th decimal digit of pi

Tags: python, algorithm, pi

**What I need:**

Function to calculate N-th **decimal** digit of Pi. Example:

```
>>> pi_digit(1)
1
>>> pi_digit(2)
4
>>> pi_digit(3)
1
>>> pi_digit(4)
5
```

**What did I tried:**

While searching, found that [code](https://github.com/jnrbsn/python-projects/blob/master/numbers/pi.py). It actually does what I need except one thing - it calculates **all** N digits, while I need only last. Is this possible to accomplish in efficient way? (if I just slice string for last character it wouldn't be so fast). Thanks in advance.

**Why I need it:**

I'm going to put that script, which would append digits to text file, onto my server and leave it for 20-30 days, and check the output.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Spigot_algorithms

Comment: @JohnColeman those are not decimal. Binary/hexadecimal, but not decimal.

Comment: Did you read this part: "no digit extraction algorithm has yet been found that rapidly produces decimal digits"? That might not be the answer you want, but it is an answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman I dont need a really fast way, but efficient way. That code, which I found, calculates digits right, but slicing for last item would be resource-unefficient. I dont care much about time, because I gonna leave it for long time.

Comment: @MaxLunar: JohnColeman answered your question perfectly. If you need the N-th binary/hexa digit, there are known algorithms to calculate it directly. If you need the N-th decimal digit, you have to calculate the N-1 first ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see:

*Unbounded Spigot Algorithms for the Digits of Pi*

**Jeremy Gibbons**

> The program under discussion is written in Haskell [5], a lazy
>   functional programming language. As a secondary point of this paper,
>   we hope to convince the reader that such languages are excellent
>   vehicles for expressing mathematical computations, certainly when
>   compared with other general-purpose programming languages such as
>   Java, C, and Pascal, and arguably even when compared with computer
>   algebra systems such as Mathematica.

https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf

it can be implemented with pidigits

> https://github.com/transmogrifier/pidigits
>
> pidigits is avalaible through Python Package Index (PyPI) using pip.

```
>>> pip install --upgrade pidigits
```

Comment: Thanks! `pidigits` is just what I need!

Comment: As far as I understand, you still need to generate n-1 digits before you can get the `n`th one.

Comment: @EricDuminil anyway, that generator works just perfect - first 2000 digits are the same as in Wiki. Now I'm going to prepare script for server.

Comment: @MaxLunar How big is `N` in your case?

Comment: @EricDuminil You mean how many digits I want to calculate? As many as possible. In that test I just done - 2000 digits

Comment: @MaxLunar: It's just that there are probably many GB files worth of pi digits on the Internet. You could trade space for very fast lookup.

Comment: @EricDuminil If i have a space and time - why not?

Comment: @MaxLunar you won't be setting any records this way, its much slower to spigot pi(0, n_places) than it is to just calculate pi(n_places); if you're after discovery the best algo is y-cruncher by Alexander Yee, but you'll give a determinate end point; currently 22 trillion places; 120 TiB of disk space; over 3 months.